# Digamma function ratio limit

Tags: gamma-function, digamma-function

I'd like to know how to go about proving the result

$$\lim_{x\to-n}\dfrac{\psi(x)}{\Gamma(x)} = (-1)^{n-1}n!$$

as it appears on p.g. 2 here http://www.math.usm.edu/lambers/mat415/lecture16.pdf.

Comment: $\bigg(\dfrac1{\Gamma(x)}\bigg)'_{x\to-n}=(-1)^n~n!$

Comment: @Lucian The OP is requesting a way to prove this.

Comment: @Dr.MV: The proof is trivial, and it follows from the reflection formula.

Comment: @lucian I wouldn't say its trivial to everyone.  And as far as I can see, it requires more than the reflection relation.  First, one needs to extend the definition of Gamma and digamma to the left-half plane by AC.  To do this, we use the functional relationship $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ repeatedly.

Comment: @Dr.MV: We are asked to find $\bigg(\dfrac1{\Gamma(-x)}\bigg)'_{x\to n}$. From Euler's reflection formula, this is equivalent to evaluating $\bigg(x!~\dfrac{\sin\pi x}\pi\bigg)'_{x\to n}$. The latter has two terms, one of which vanishes.

Comment: @lucian The reflection relationship holds for $|x|$<1$, does it not?

Comment: @Dr.MV: It holds for the entire domain of the $\Gamma$ function.

Comment: @Lucian Well, one still needs a way of extending $\Gamma$ by analytic continuation.  And of course, if one uses the reflection relationship, it would be natural to ask "How does one prove the reflection relationship?"  The point I was making is that the OP, I believe, is asking for a first principles development such as the one that I posted.

Comment: @Dr.MV: A rough sketch can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/714668/1).

Comment: @Lucian I know how to prove it, but that wasn't really my point.  Again, I believe that the OP is seeking a first principles proof, which is what I tried to provide.  By using the reflection formula, one would need to have proved the product formulae for both $\Gamma (z)$ and $\sin z$ or be well-versed in complex plane analysis (Liouville, max mod, harmonic functions, bounds for $\Gamma (z)$ and $\sin z$ in parts of the plane, etc.).  So, I appreciate your approach, but I am not sure that it is fit-for-purpose for the OP.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that the analytic continuation of the Gamma function can be obtained by using repeatedly the functional relationship $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$.  Then, for $x+m+1>0$, we can write

$$\Gamma (x)=\frac{\Gamma(x+m+1)}{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+m-1)(x+m)} \tag 1$$

Using $(1)$ reveals that for $x+m+1>0$, the digamma function can be expressed as

$$\psi(x)=\frac{d\log \Gamma (x)}{dx}=\psi(x+m+1)-\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{x+k} \tag 2$$

Therefore, using $(1)$ and $(2)$, the ratio $\frac{\psi(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$ is given by

$$\frac{\psi(x)}{\Gamma(x)}=\left(\psi(x+m+1)-\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{1}{x+k}\right)\left(\frac{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+m-1)(x+m)}{\Gamma(x+m+1)}\right) \tag 3$$

For $0<n\le m$, we note that for $x=-n$, $\Gamma(x+m+1)=(m-n)!$ and $\psi(x+m+1)=H_{m+1-n}-\gamma$.  Therefore, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to -n}\frac{\psi(x)}{\Gamma(x)}&=\lim_{x\to -n}\left(\frac{\psi(x+m+1)}{\Gamma(x+m+1)}\left(x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+m-1)(x+m)\right)\right)\\\\
&-\lim_{x\to -n}\left(\frac{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+m-1)(x+m)}{\Gamma(x+m+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{x+k}\right)\\\\
&=-\lim_{x\to -n}\left(\frac{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+m-1)(x+m)}{\Gamma(x+m+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{1}{x+k}\right)\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{(m-n)!}\lim_{x\to -n}\sum_{k=0}^m\frac{x(x+1)(x+2)\cdots(x+m-1)(x+m)}{x+k}\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{(m-n)!}\left((-n)(-n+1)(-n+2)\cdots (-2)(-1)(1)(2)\cdots(m-n-1)(m-n)\right)\\\\
&=-(1)^{n+1}n!
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: Please let me know how I can improve my answer. I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: Thank you very much -- this is exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.
From the main body of working could you please tell me how the first of the limit terms is eliminated and how the penultimate line follows from the previous.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Since $x\to -n$ all terms without a $1/(x+n)$ go to zero.  And similarly, we arrive at the pentultimate expression follow since the $(x+n)$ term in the numerator is precisely compensated by the term for $k=n$ in the summation.

Comment: Understood, thank you. I'm not familiar with many of the other tools Lucien mentioned to prove the result more trivially.

Comment: Yes.  I wanted to present a way forward that did not rely on a relationship (i.e., the reflection formula) that is not easy to intuitively understand or prove with standard tools.